# What is the name of a device and its parts that has a component turning the other circuit on/off in reverse of the component's state?

Tags: automation

Specifically, if such a device exists, what would it be called?

To explain my usage scenario, I have battery powered and solar charged flood lights attached to my truck; they automatically turn off when they charge AKA it's sun light out. In addition to that, because I also drive at night, when I stop and leave the vehicle and turn it off, I want the flood lights to turn on.

I'm either looking for a device that monitors voltage by being connected to the ignition's or front light's connectors on the fuse panel to monitor current flow. Then if there's a current, thus ignition or front lights are on, the flood lights' circuit would be automatically interrupted, thus turning the lights off.

Of course I can just use a switch that I'd manually have to use to turn all the flood lights on/off, but I'd just like to instead automate the whole process.

I'd be much grateful for any suggestions for what such a device is called if it exists.

Comment: @Justme - in short: no. Long explanation of my response: my question was for the name of what such a device would be called, not the component (ie. "relay").

Comment: The device you need is called a relay with normally closed contact, but if you don't like this word, we could create a new one from the functional perspective of your application, I suggest "negator".

Comment: logic inverter  or  NOT gate